# HtmlAgilityPack doesnt work

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, windows

I have two windows application by using HtmlAgilityPack .
HtmlAgilityPack doesn't work in my project currently .
It show " The debugger could not locate the source file 'D:\Source\htmlagilitypack.new\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlNodeCollection.cs' ". 
Is there any other method to do the same work as HtmlAgilityPack ?
I cant find the problem. I need some help . Thank You

Comment: For emergencies call 911 or your local emergency number. For questions on SO please provide details beyond "need help immediately".

Comment: what's the difference between them?

Comment: @lrnab I've had problems with htmlagilitypack even as a Nuget package.

Comment: @ErikE Well post a question with your problem and hopefully you will find a solution on SO.

Comment: @user3322320 Nuget will take care of any reference problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4558654/397817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all your HtmlAgilityPack dll from your reference and after removing make sure that all the HtmlAgilityPack dll is removed (to check press control F and type HtmlAgilityPack and press enter). then freshly add the HtmlAgilityPack dll. then your problem is solved..

Answer (score 0):

You are using the dll of HtmlAgilityPack as reference. Try using the source then the debugger will know where **HtmlNodeCollection.cs** is.

Comment: Go here: [Changesets](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets). Download the source you like.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try the this...**

Visual Studio -> Debug -> [Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5bWH.png) -> Check both "Enable Just My Code" and "Warn if no user code on lunch (Managed Only)"